# ATDD test relation with TDD test

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd, atdd

The basic cycle of ATDD is after we write acceptance test, we write TDD test of that acceptance test.
But my question is how could you specify which unit tests is relate to which acceptance test?
Would it be possible by the feature we've done ATDD and TDD about that or some other techniques?

Comment: unit tests are independent from acceptance tests

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1:1 relationship between unit tests and acceptance tests. A acceptance test specifies expectations about a feature (i.e. some high level concept). A unit test specifies expectations about a unit (i.e. some low level concept). Such a unit might be used to implement a broad range of features. Therefore the unit test might be related to a number of acceptance tests. Just because the unit was implemented to satisfy a acceptance test does not mean that it belongs to it.